# Visual Studio 2013 Performance

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I recently 'upgraded' to Visual Studio 2013, Upgrade 3 and I am horrified at its Performance. It becomes unresponsive when trying to complete the most simple tasks( Like creating a New Project ) and builds are taking more than 30 mins. Does anyone have any suggestions on speeding it up? I have trying unchecking 'Rich client experience' but it made no difference?? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'd investigate using the techniques described in the various [the case of the unexplained](https://www.google.com/#q=the+case+of+the+unexplained) materials by Mark Russinovich.

Comment: Is there anything I can do regarding its thread management, there seems to be loads of problems stemming from this, becomeing un-responsive like every 20 seconds for example....

Comment: Well, I'd start with eliminating add-ons - they can easily do funny stuff. For example, I used to get lots of crashes from Reflector add-on (I think it's better now).